# jQuery - targeting Sibilings , Parents , Descendents and other family animals

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, siblings, targeting

I had a small markup test for toggling a div .

A (working) mockup can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/d78aF/1/

The problem is , that I need the Hide / Show link to be placed in ANOTHER div , like here :

http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/d78aF/2/

.. and when I move it , it does not work for all my efforts .

I have tried :

`jQuery(this).next().next('.toggle').toggle('slow');`

and

`jQuery(this).next('.toggle').toggle('slow');`

and many others, but it is just trial and error - whereas I would like to understand this family stuff (I guess me not being a family person is subconscensly infl;icting on my coding ability :- ) )

Speaking of understanding , In one of my trial and errors , I have made this :

http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/d78aF/5/

which is NOT working , but adding a small `</br>` suddenly makes it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/d78aF/4/

Does an empty `</br>` tag is considered a "sibling" ??

Comment: Appreciate your efforts to explain the problem using fiddle but I think it is still confusing, can you explain in simple terms what exactly are you looking to do? (forget about the fiddle for a while)

Comment: What I want is to toggle a DIV from a link which is positioned WITHIN a previous div .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this one: http://jsfiddle.net/d78aF/6/

```
jQuery(this).siblings('.toggle').toggle('slow');
```

As per your comment you can do this way: http://jsfiddle.net/d78aF/7/

```
jQuery(document).find('.toggle').toggle('slow');
```

new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d78aF/8/

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but in your fidddle that link element is positioned exactly like in my first (working ) example . When I move it up to the previous div It does not work as well ( my second example)

Comment: ok, that seems to work, but the whole markup is changed .. The whole second div is moved . Is there a way of doing so WITHOUT moving the second div , just the link ?

Comment: yep, i am sorry, I just tried, and it DOES work on this specific example . thanks . somehow however on the REAL website markup, it is still not working for me , but I guess I have some other unresolved issues ..

Answer (score 1):

> Does an empty `</br>` tag is considered a "sibling" ??

What don't you try by yourself?

```
<div id='firstEl'></div>
<br/>
<div></div>

<div id='siblings'></div>
```

Then in your js code:

```
$(function(){
  $('#siblings').text($.makeArray($('#firstEl').siblings()).join(','));
});
```

Results:

```
[object HTMLBRElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement]
```

You can see that the `<br/>` element is considered as a siblings

http://jsfiddle.net/EP5bj/

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: Thanks, I saw that in my examples above, I just do not understand the "why" - but that is my lacuna . In the meantime, how can I target the right div in the right way in my question ? .

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a more targeted approach, where in the HTML markup you specify what div is to be hid. This is a common practice with many packages, such as jQuery Mobile.

http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/R5sDr/

```
<p class="hider" for="banks">Hide the banks!</p>

$(".hider").click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("for");
    $("#" + id).hide("slow");
    log("Hiding #" + id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice .. but this markup is a part of a LIST , which have many items with same class , but  without IDs..